# ansible: run task multiple times on the same host, using variables from another

Tags: ansible

New to *ansible*, can't find a reference for my issue which does not seem so rare..

I have two hosts under the same group, each of them with its variables, say:

```
[myHosts]
host1  a=1  b=10
host2  a=2  b=20
```

Now, I have a task which needs to be executed twice on `host1` only, once with `host1`'s variables, and the second time with the value of `a` from `host1`, and `b` from `host2`.
If I write it this way:

```
- role: my_role
      vars:
        a_val: {{ a }}
        b_val: {{ b }}
      loop: "{{ groups['myHosts'] }}"
      when: inventory_hostname in groups['myHosts'][0]
```

I get `a_val` and `b_val` populated with `host1` values only (which is fine for `a_val`, not for `b_val`).

I know there seems to be no reason why I could just call the same task twice referencing the proper value of `b` with some ansible magic vars (`hostvars[groups['myHosts'][1]]['b']` would do the trick for example), **but the hosts could be 10 tomorrow** and that would be annoying (in that case, the `when` condition would still be fine, since everything will be executed always there).

How can I generalize to have `b_val` populated with the proper value?

Answer (score 0):

> Q: *"A task which needs to be executed twice on host1 only, once with host1's variables, and the second time with the value of a from host1, and b from host2."*

A: [hostvars](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_variables.html#accessing-information-about-other-hosts-with-magic-variables) lets you access variables for another host. For example the play

```
- hosts: host1
  tasks:
    - debug:
        msg: "a:{{ item.a }} b:{{ item.b }}"
      loop:
        - "{'a': {{ a }}, 'b': {{ b }} }"
        - "{'a': {{ a }}, 'b': {{ hostvars['host2'].b }} }"
```

gives

```
ok: [host1] => (item={'a': 1, 'b': 10}) => {
    "msg": "a:1 b:10"
}
ok: [host1] => (item={'a': 1, 'b': 20}) => {
    "msg": "a:1 b:20"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is what I needed: https://stackoverflow.com/a/32336359/827818

I made a separate list like that:

```
bs_list:
  host1:
    b: val1
  host2:
    b: val2
```

included with a `pre_tasks`, and then

```
- debug: 
    msg: "{{ item.value.b }}"
  with_dict: "{{ bs_list }}"
  when: inventory_hostname in groups['myHosts'][0]
```